# Modification to change the input from array to bulk code. (Code provided and working)

Tags: php, regex

how can I modify my function to make use of

```
<select name="extra2"  id="extra2" class="select_smaller">
    <option value="Algema">Algema</option>
    <option value="Barkas">Barkas</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

that I have on my forms and then creates the array input of the function below to get it work ?
`$options = array('Algema', 'Barkas', 'Cadillac', …);`

If this is not possible or a big thing, we can avoid the *"get from dropdown list and create me an array input"* and 
just use the dropdown list as is, to produce my desired output.

The result is correct, the code works great but what I want is to avoid the copy-paste around 200 different dropdown lists with about 10 options each. Instead I will use a program for mass text input to paste the code in the front and end of the lists.

```
function makeSelect($name, $options) {
    foreach ($options as &$option) {
        $selected = isset($_GET[$name]) && $_GET[$name] == $option;
        $option = sprintf('<option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s</option>',
                          htmlspecialchars($option),
                          $selected ? ' selected="selected"' : null);
    }

    return sprintf('<select name="%1$s" id="%1$s" class="select">%2$s</select>',
                   htmlspecialchars($name),
                   join($options));
}

$options = array('Algema', 'Barkas', 'Cadillac', …);
// instead of array I prefer to use here something $options=the dropdown list as is.
    echo makeSelect('car', $options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions, for example (assuming `$list_html` contains HTML in the form you have cited):

```
$count = preg_match_all('/<option value=\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"\>/', $list_html, $matches);
if ($count) {
    // something has been found
    $found_values = $matches[1];
} else {
    $found_values = array();
}
```

This has been tested. If you assign value in the following way:

```
$list_html = '<select name="extra2"  id="extra2" class="select_smaller">'
    .'<option value="Algema">Algema</option>'
    .'<option value="Barkas">Barkas</option>'
    .'</select>';
```

and do `print_r($found_values)`, the result will be:

```
Array ( [0] => Algema [1] => Barkas )
```

And that means, you get proper values for each option in array. Assuming of course, that these values contain small letters, big letters or ciphers, but nothing more (otherwise the regular expression has to be adjusted to meet your needs).

**EDIT:**

For your convenience, the same thing in form of a function:

```
/**
 * Get all values of 'option' tags in given HTML
 * @param string $list_html 
 * @return array values of option tags or empty array if none
 */
function extractOptionValues($list_html) {
    $regex = '/<option value=\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"\>/';
    $count = preg_match_all($regex, $list_html, $matches);
    if ($count) {
        $found_values = $matches[1];
    } else {
        $found_values = array();
    }
    return $found_values;
}
```

Now it should be ok to do it in the following way:

```
$options = extractOptionValues($list_html); // $list_html contains select HTML
```

**EDIT 2:**

The same mechanism included within your function could look like that:

```
/**
 * Return HTML of select field with one option selected, built based
 * on the list of options provided
 * @param mixed $options array of options or HTML of select form field
 * @return string HTML of the select field
 */
function makeSelect($name, $options) {

    if (is_string($options)) {
        // assuming the options string given is HTML of select field
        $regex = '/<option value=\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"\>/';
        $count = preg_match_all($regex, $options, $matches);
        if ($count) {
            $options = $matches[1];
        } else {
            $options = array();
        }
    }

    foreach ($options as &$option) {
        $selected = isset($_GET[$name]) && $_GET[$name] == $option;
        $option = sprintf('<option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s</option>',
                          htmlspecialchars($option),
                          $selected ? ' selected="selected"' : null);
    }

    return sprintf('<select name="%1$s" id="%1$s" class="select">%2$s</select>',
                   htmlspecialchars($name),
                   join($options));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me check it! But how can I migrate it with my existing code?

Comment: I do not know any details about your code. You said you need values of options in a form of array - the function I have recently added to my answer is exactly for that. It should also help you integrate it with your code. All you need is to, if I understand you correctly, get selects' HTML somehow from wherever you store it and pass it to that function to get the values you need for your own function.

Comment: Well, what I want is to have exactly what you posted me. But after this I have to migrate it with my code I posted to return me it's result. I will check it and come back to you.

Comment: Ok, no problem. The separate function for that is not needed - we can make the function `makeSelect()` recognize this is code to be processed, not an array, and then turn it into an array. If you have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: Tadek what if I used your preg_match_all or anything else that should just get my input and create a variable in the form of `'Algema', 'Barkas', 'Cadillac', …` as it is in my function? I would replace it with the variable to work.

Comment: I do not follow. Can you give me some example? I will provide the updated version of your function to show you what I meant.

Comment: Ok, this is now updated - if your function is given string of selects' HTML instead of array in `$options` parameter, the `makeSelect()` function should convert it on its own. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: Working great! How can we replace this `echo makeSelect('car', $options);` with `echo makeSelect('$selectid', $options);` to get the name of the selectbox automatically ?

Comment: You have to perform `preg_match()` function on string containing the select's HTML. If you will be passed HTML to that function, you do not need anything else - just rewrite your function to find value of `name` attribute within `select` tag in a similar way I got `value` attribute from `option` tag. Then use it in a way you use `$name` variable in your function.

Comment: Got you! What is the regex I should use to get the name?

Comment: If the select tag looks the same as you have listed in your question, the regexp can be `/<select name=\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"\>/` and will match name of select defined using `<select name="test1">`, `<select name="xyz">` or any other written in that way and having only letters and/or ciphers in its `name` attribute. And use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), which is similar to `preg_match_all()`, but quicker and it works in this case (one match needed).

Comment: Tadeck can you edit your code because I can't do it correctly? I would be very thankful if you do it.

Comment: Ok, but I need sample code for the select (at least starting with `<select` and ending with first `>`) to make it correctly. You said code extracting options works?

Comment: Yes code works great. As I said I want not to manually set the name like `echo makeSelect('car', $options);` but automatically like `echo makeSelect('$selectid', $options);`. This is my code for select `<select name="extra1"  id="extra1" class="select">`